# How to select two sets of year with a datetime index and loc?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, slice, multi-index

I'm currently deal with a dataframe of hundred thousands lines and more, with an index made by datetime values.

You can create a micro sample of my dataframe with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2015', end='1/1/2020', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['Date'])
df['Value'] = np.random.randint(0,1000, len(dates))
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

I would like to select all the '2015' and 2018' year, or '2015-01' and '2015-06'.
I know how to slice between two values with `SliceIndex`. I know how to get one whole year, but I do not know how to get two whole years with `loc`.

```
df['2015'] # it works
df[(slice('2015', '2016')] # or df['2015':'2016']

# but
df[['2015', '2016']] # it does not work.
```

In fact I have a mutli-index. To build an example:

```
df1 = df.copy()
df['lvl0'] = ['a']*len(df)
df1['lvl0'] = ['b']*len(df)
mlti_df = pd.concat([df, df1]).reset_index().set_index(['lvl0', 'Date'])

mlti_df[(slice(None), ['2015', '2016'])] # <= does not work
```

Is it possible to get row by this way? I found no answer by looking for during hours yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`partial string indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) working only with one year, not list of years.

I think you need [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with extract years by [`DatetimeIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html) and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.index.year.isin([2015, 2016])]
print (df1)
                     Value
Date                      
2015-01-01 00:00:00    858
2015-01-01 01:00:00    807
2015-01-01 02:00:00    895
2015-01-01 03:00:00    159
2015-01-01 04:00:00    176
                   ...
2016-12-31 19:00:00    888
2016-12-31 20:00:00    162
2016-12-31 21:00:00    207
2016-12-31 22:00:00    545
2016-12-31 23:00:00     49

[17544 rows x 1 columns]
```

And for `MultiIndex` solution is simialr, only add [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html):

```
df2 = mlti_df[mlti_df.index.get_level_values('Date').year.isin([2015, 2016])]
print (df2)
                          Value
lvl0 Date                      
a    2015-01-01 00:00:00    626
     2015-01-01 01:00:00    941
     2015-01-01 02:00:00    405
     2015-01-01 03:00:00    249
     2015-01-01 04:00:00    320
                        ...
b    2016-12-31 19:00:00    752
     2016-12-31 20:00:00    829
     2016-12-31 21:00:00    843
     2016-12-31 22:00:00    306
     2016-12-31 23:00:00     96

[35088 rows x 1 columns]
```